# How to get Chrome command line switches from js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

There are many command line switches in Chrome, for example: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Is there an option to check by javascript which of them are enabled?

Comment: That would be a huge security hole, wouldn't you think?

Comment: @Gomby, in my context security is't issue (it's for app which runs on embedded device and have no access to external networks, and it's already have --disable-web-security for easier integration with hardware). We use certain chrome flags, but a need to see them from app arised, and if it can't be done by js we need duplicate this flag somewhere where app can access it. Im trying avoid that duplication by direct access to chrome flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. And there shouldn't be any need for it. If a flag adds any functionality, you can check if that functionality exists. Any other flag is completely irrelevant to a webpage.