# Programmatically disable canvas hardware acceleration in browser

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, canvas

I'm working on a project which uses a Canvas to render content. Testing with Chrome 37 on an android tablet gives rendering artefacts. Namely black bloxes.

Disabling the Canvas hardware accelaration via chrome://flags results in correct rendering of the canvas.

Is there a way to disable the canvas hardware acceleration? Preferably via CSS or javascript?

Answer (score 3):

This is an older question, but the answer is still the same, no there is not. Disabling via `chrome://flags` or at the [command line/shortcut](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) are the only way to disable/enable any of the chrome switches (flags).

It's a browser level thing and out of the scope of the ECMAScript and CSS spec -- you [cannot even check which switches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25682100/1992129) are enabled/disabled programmatically. The switches/flags exist for developmental purposes and can be removed without any notice.